# ldap_bind(...) php gives invalid credentials while ldp.exe works

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I have serious trouble figuring out which credentials to use to connect to the ad in php.
I can connect successfully using ldp.exe with generic function type and the right domain, user, and password. With any other option set in ldp.exe I can only connect anonymous.

In php I have no chance. I'm not very familiar with ldap, so I am kinda lost here.
Here some php code:

```
$ldap_host = "ldap://<dc>:389";
$ldap_user = "<username>";
$ldap_pw = "<pw>";
$ldap_domain = "<full domain>";

$connection = ldap_connect($ldap_host) or die("Could not connect to LDAP server."); 

//$user = $ldap_user;
$user = $ldap_user."@".$ldap_domain;
//$user = $ldap_user;
//$user = "uid=".$ldap_user;
//$user = $ldap_domain."\\".$ldap_user;
//$user = "User=$ldap_user";
//$user = "cn=".$ldap_user;
//$user = "CN=".$ldap_user.",OU=<someOU>,OU=<someOU>,DC=<DC1>,DC=<DC2>";

ldap_bind($connection, $user, $ldap_pw);
```

You can see there some combinations I tried. In ldp.exe it is just the $ldap_user in the username field and $ldap_domain in the domain field. Imho atleast the user@domain and domain\user version should work. It is a kerberos domain, if thats important.

Well I don't think there are code errors. But how do I translate the generic function type of ldp.exe into php?

Here the error message to make it easier to find:

```
Warning: ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Invalid credentials in ...
```

I would really appreciate some help.

EDIT: In ldp.exe I seem to use the SSPI method. I thought generic picks the method it self so far. Does it have something to do with ldap_sasl_bind() ? The server specifies on connection he is capable of the following:

```
supportedSASLMechanisms: GSSAPI; GSS-SPNEGO; EXTERNAL; DIGEST-MD5;
```

While only GSSAPI (SSPI ????) seems to work.

EDIT2: Here some other output of ldp.exe after an successful authentication:

```
res = ldap_bind_s(ld, NULL, &NtAuthIdentity, 1158); // v.3
    {NtAuthIdentity: User='<username>'; Pwd= <unavailable>; domain = '<full domain'.}
Authenticated as dn:'<username>'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the port as well into a variable

```
$ldapPort = 389;
```

I would ignore the host part and just try connecting to your server (you have it as domain) Check to see if your ldap bind is working

```
// Handle login requests
$ds = ldap_connect($ldapServer, $ldapPort);
if (ldap_bind($ds, $user, $password)) {
  // Successful auth
  $_SESSION['lastactivity'] = time();
  $_SESSION['username'] = $user;
  $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
  return $ds;
} else {
  // Auth failed
  header("Location: failpage.php?fail=1"); //bad credentials
  exit;
}
```

Also for calling all the attributes, try http://blog.uta.edu/jthardy/2007/08/08/obtaining-user-information-from-ldap-using-php/

Comment: The connection to the server works fine. You see the warning the script gives. Its the only warning I get. The credentials I enter are invalid.

Comment: And the domain differs from the host.